# Is there a way to store output dataframes and appending them to the last output in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to fetch data from API for 50 parcels. I want them to be in a single data frame. While running this loop the data frame is storing only the last parcel which is satisfying the loop condition. Is there any way to store all the previous outputs also in the same dataframe.

For e.g upon running this code it only returns the data frame for foreign id=50, I want the dataframe for all 1-50.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
foreign=1
while (foreign <=50):

    s1_time_series_url_p6 = 'https://demodev2.kappazeta.ee/ard_api_demo/v1/time_series/s1?limit_to_rasters=true&parcel_foreign_id=0&properties=parcel_foreign_id%2Cs1product_end_time%2Cs1product_ron%2Ccohvh_avg%2Ccohvv_avg%2Cvhvv_avg'
    s2_time_series_url_p6 = 'https://demodev2.kappazeta.ee/ard_api_demo/v1/time_series/s2?limit_to_rasters=true&parcel_foreign_id=0&properties=parcel_foreign_id%2Cs2product_start_time%2Cs2product_ron%2Cndvi_avg'
    position = 101
    foreign_n=str(foreign)
    s1_time_series_url_p6 = s1_time_series_url_p6[:position] + foreign_n + s1_time_series_url_p6[position+1:]
    s2_time_series_url_p6 = s2_time_series_url_p6[:position] + foreign_n + s2_time_series_url_p6[position+1:]
    r_s1_time_series_p6 = requests.get(s1_time_series_url_p6)
    r_s2_time_series_p6 = requests.get(s2_time_series_url_p6)
    json_s1_time_series_p6 = r_s1_time_series_p6.json()
    json_s2_time_series_p6 = r_s2_time_series_p6.json()
    df_s1_time_series_p6 = pd.DataFrame(json_s1_time_series_p6['s1_time_series'])
    df_s2_time_series_p6 = pd.DataFrame(json_s2_time_series_p6['s2_time_series'])
    df_s2_time_series_p6.s2product_start_time=df_s2_time_series_p6.s2product_start_time.str[0:11]
    df_s1_time_series_p6.s1product_end_time=df_s1_time_series_p6.s1product_end_time.str[0:11]
    dfinal_p6 = df_s1_time_series_p6.merge(df_s2_time_series_p6, how='inner', left_on='s1product_end_time', right_on='s2product_start_time')
    cols_p6 = ['parcel_foreign_id_x', 's1product_ron','parcel_foreign_id_y','s2product_ron']
    dfinal_p6[cols_p6] = dfinal_p6[cols_p6].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
dfinal_p6
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by first creating an empty data frame and then appending the outputs in the dataframe within the loop.

The updated code is as follows:

```
column_names = ["parcel_foreign_id_x", "s1product_end_time", "s1product_ron","cohvh_avg", "cohvv_avg", "vhvv_avg","parcel_foreign_id_y", "s2product_start_time", "s2product_ron", "ndvi_avg" ]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

foreign=1

while (foreign <=50):


    s1_time_series_url_p6 = 'https://demodev2.kappazeta.ee/ard_api_demo/v1/time_series/s1?limit_to_rasters=true&parcel_foreign_id=0&properties=parcel_foreign_id%2Cs1product_end_time%2Cs1product_ron%2Ccohvh_avg%2Ccohvv_avg%2Cvhvv_avg'
    s2_time_series_url_p6 = 'https://demodev2.kappazeta.ee/ard_api_demo/v1/time_series/s2?limit_to_rasters=true&parcel_foreign_id=0&properties=parcel_foreign_id%2Cs2product_start_time%2Cs2product_ron%2Cndvi_avg'
    position = 101
    foreign_n=str(foreign)
    s1_time_series_url_p6 = s1_time_series_url_p6[:position] + foreign_n + s1_time_series_url_p6[position+1:]
    s2_time_series_url_p6 = s2_time_series_url_p6[:position] + foreign_n + s2_time_series_url_p6[position+1:]
    r_s1_time_series_p6 = requests.get(s1_time_series_url_p6)
    r_s2_time_series_p6 = requests.get(s2_time_series_url_p6)
    json_s1_time_series_p6 = r_s1_time_series_p6.json()
    json_s2_time_series_p6 = r_s2_time_series_p6.json()
    df_s1_time_series_p6 = pd.DataFrame(json_s1_time_series_p6['s1_time_series'])
    df_s2_time_series_p6 = pd.DataFrame(json_s2_time_series_p6['s2_time_series'])
    df_s2_time_series_p6.s2product_start_time=df_s2_time_series_p6.s2product_start_time.str[0:11]
    df_s1_time_series_p6.s1product_end_time=df_s1_time_series_p6.s1product_end_time.str[0:11]
    dfinal_p6 = df_s1_time_series_p6.merge(df_s2_time_series_p6, how='inner', left_on='s1product_end_time', right_on='s2product_start_time')
    cols_p6 = ['parcel_foreign_id_x', 's1product_ron','parcel_foreign_id_y','s2product_ron']
    dfinal_p6[cols_p6] = dfinal_p6[cols_p6].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([dfinal_p6,df],ignore_index = True)
    foreign = foreign+1
```